# Creating an $n\times n$ grid with specified $2\times2$ sums

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose we have an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ grid $A$ with numbers in each cell.

How can we efficiently create a new $n \times n$ grid $B$ of digits where each $A_{i,j}$ is the sum of the corresponding $2\times 2$ subgrid of $B\,$?

In other words:
\begin{align}
B_{i,j} &\in \{0, 1, \ldots 9\}\\
A_{i,j} &= B_{i,j} + B_{i+1,j} + B_{i,j+1} + B_{i+1,j+1}
\end{align}

Obviously it is not always possible to create such a $B$. So, assume that the grid $A$ has at least 1 corresponding $B$. There is a brute force $10^{n^2}$ approach which generates all possible grids, but I am looking for an efficient solution. n is <= 100.

Comment: This seems like an algorithms problem, not a research mathematics problem.

Comment: I posted it on stackoverflow too. I thought that there might be a clever greedy algo/constructive algo solution to it.

Comment: If we first choose the new $2n-1$  digits of $B_{ij}$ in $10^{2n-1}$ ways, then we can find $c_{i,j}B_{ij}-B_{i+1,j+1}=A_{i,j}-(A_{i+1,j}+A_{i,j+1})+(A_{i+2,j}+A_{i,j+2})-(A_{i+3,j}+A_{i,j+3})-..+$ for all $i,j$s as we had already selected some $B_{n,j}$ and $B_{i,n}$s. Then By adding $c_{i,j}+c_{i+1,j+1}+c_{i+2,j+2}+...$ we get $B_{i,j}$, for all $i,j$.

Comment: I just edited. n is approximately 100 and thus any exponential solution in n may not work.

Comment: @LSpice : the mathematics lies in the finding of some (other) structure on ${A}, {B}$ which allows for efficient solving. It seems to me a system of linear discrete equations, I know nothing about this so I cannot judge how research-worthy the question is. On the other hand I cannot find any easy references either. So I will upvote, just to encourage others to shine their light.